# Why does Swagger include unnecessary variables into the request URL?

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am currently traing to document my REST interface "/news/rest/v1/articles" using Swagger2 and Spring MVC. It looks like this:

```
@RestController
@Api(
        description = "My News interface",
        produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
)
public class NewsController {
    @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/news/rest/v1/articles",
            produces = {"application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    )
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Returns news according to the given limit and language"
    )
    @ApiResponses(
            value = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            code = 503,
                            message = "in case the news cannot be retrieved"
                    )
            }
    )
    public String getNews(
            @ApiParam(
                    value = "limitation of news elements",
                    required = false,
                    defaultValue = "-1" // -1 means no limitation
            )
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "-1")
            Integer limit,

            @ApiParam(
                    value = "the language",
                    required = true,
                    allowableValues = "de,fr,it,en"
            )
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "de")
            @Valid
            @Pattern(regexp = "de|fr|it|en")
            String language

            throws HTTPException {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

If I deploy my app and navigate to the Swagger-UI, everything looks just fine, except for the fact that I cannot use the "Try it out!"-button. The problem is that the generated URL used by Swagger is somewhat weird...It looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/news/rest/v1/articles{?limit,language}?limit=-1&language=de
```

I cannot quite get my head around why the string "{?limit,language}" is included into the request URL. If I manually call that very URL without the "{?limit,language}" string, it works just fine...

I'd appreciate it very much if somebody could give me a pointer on this.

Best regards
Walter

Comment: Because your method expects them.

Comment: What does that mean? Of course, the method expects those parameters...

Comment: Then why do you ask? The generated URL just tells you that. `{ }` is a template placeholder in case you don't know that.

Comment: When hitting "Try it out!"-button, Swagger calls "http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/news/rest/v1/articles{?limit,language}?limit=-1&language=de" instead of "http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/news/rest/v1/articles?limit=-1&language=de". Why is the string "{?limit,language}" included in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using @RequestParam annotated method with swagger ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377388/using-requestparam-annotated-method-with-swagger-ui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem here: [Using @RequestParam annotated method with swagger ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377388/using-requestparam-annotated-method-with-swagger-ui)

You need to set

```
enableUrlTemplating(false)
```

in `Docket` configuration