# @RequestParam annotated method with swagger ui not showing description

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am attempting to mold Swagger-UI in order to modify not only that "name" field but also the "Description" field of an API input parameter. An example is here of someone appearing to do this successfully, utilizing both @ApiParam and @RequestParam: [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377388/using-requestparam-annotated-method-with-swagger-ui)

The closest to modifying the description field I have come so far is the following, where I used the "value" field alone on the @RequestParam input:

[image]

However, whenever I try to implement the same structure utilizing both @ApiParam and @RequestParam annotations on a single input element, as shown on the example of the other user above, I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with the annotations here? Is it that this can't be done on a @RequestMapping annotated API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `,` In between `@ApiParam` `value` and `name` properties

```
@ApiParam(value="Use GET...", name="schoolId")
```

Comment: This was part of it, thank you! The other part seems to have been that I was missing a library import:

`import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;`

Comment: Once I confirm that this was the issue, I'll accept the answer.