# Why SwaggerUI show Validation error after uploading image?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger-ui

I have created API using Spring Boot for uploading images and then returning how many faces are in that image.

Below is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/facedetect")
@CrossOrigin
public class FaceDetectController {

    @Autowired
    FaceDetectService faceDetectService;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String getFaceCount(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        String faceCount = faceDetectService.getFaceCount(image);
        return "Count + " +faceCount;
    }


}
```

After uploading the image `getFaceCount` method will return `faceCount`.

After I generated swagger UI documentation for it. After uploading the image it shows the below error.

[image: Swagger UI error]

I think this is because of `@RequestParam("image")` annotation. Because when I used POSTMAN it didn't show any error.

[image: Postman]

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Value of consumes should should be "multipart/form-data". consumes="multipart/form-data" & method should be POST in case image is too large. Let's specify your method with

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
```

Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/47519825/6633045

Answer (score 0):

Try using @ApiOperation(value = "Get the count of faces in an image") annotation.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/facedetect")
@CrossOrigin
public class FaceDetectController {

    @Autowired
    FaceDetectService faceDetectService;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get the count of faces in an image")
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String getFaceCount(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        faceDetectService.getFaceCount(image);
        return "Count";
    }
}
```

If it is not useful plz try like below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/facedetect")
@CrossOrigin
public class FaceDetectController {

    @Autowired
    FaceDetectService faceDetectService;

    @PostMapping("/get")
    public String getFaceCount(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        String faceCount = faceDetectService.getFaceCount(image);
        return "Count : " +faceCount;
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String getFaceCount(@RequestParam("imagePath") String imagePath) throws IOException {
        // Process imagePath and return the result
        String faceCount = faceDetectService.getFaceCountUsingOnlyPath(imagePath);
        return "Count:-- " + faceCount;
    }
```

Now you can give image path like below.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/facedetect/get?imagePath={give image path}
```

Then you cn give image path in Swagger ui.Check below image.

[image]

Check below link for more info..

[@RequestParam annotated method with swagger ui not showing description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401304/requestparam-annotated-method-with-swagger-ui-not-showing-description)